# php error when accessing a particular web site

Tags: website, php

I'm trying to login into sitejot and I get the error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 50 seconds exceeded
 in /home/sitejot/public_html/login.php on line 23
```

- It only happens on one pc, all other pc's at my house do not encounter this error
- It happens consistently every time regardless of browser - IE, Firefox, Chrome
- I can move the pc to be behind another router and the error remains
- It is particular to this web page, other pages in the same web site are ok, and I don't have any problems with any other web pages
- Googling "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 50 seconds exceeded" returns a huge number of hits, so this seems to be a common problem
- I've upgraded my pc to Windows 7 with no improvement

Here is the **POST request**:

```
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1 
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, 
  application/x-ms-xbap, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, 
  application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, */*
Referer: http://www.sitejot.com/
Accept-Language: en-CA User-Agent:
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2;
  .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; 
  Media Center PC 6.0; Media Center PC 5.0; SLCC1) 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Host: www.sitejot.com 
Content-Length: 55
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Pragma: no-cache
```

There's is no response and eventually it times out. Here is the **response header**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2009 05:15:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.61 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.61 
   OpenSSL/0.9.7a mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.2.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.5
Set-Cookie: sj_user=
Set-Cookie: sj_pw=
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 144
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

What can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: Way too localised, but *may* be informative for others who see this on other sites and wonder what's up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with the website itself. It appears that they have poorly written code on their end. Particularly with the login script.

It could be a loop that never ends, a resource they aren't able to access or any other thing.

It is no fault of yours, unless you count wanting to log into their site as a user error.

Either way, it's localised to their site and to this page.

Answer (score 2):

Eight Days is spot on; this is a problem with the website itself.

You should contact the site's owner/support staff and let them know about the problem.  File a bug report with them.  They may need information from you regarding the configuration of the machine that fails vs the machines that work.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll link to this page when I contact them.